# Displaying specific csv field info in visual basic listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a 2 column csv file: 
11111,0001.jpg
22222,0002.jpg
33333,0003.jpg

I am building a visual basic windows form app in visual studio 2013. The app will have a text box and browse button on one side. The textbox displays the file location selected with the browse button. on the other side of the app are two listboxes. I have listbox1 displaying the first column of my csv file. I would like the 2nd listbox, listbox2, display only the last 4 characters in the 2nd column of my csv file. Here is my code so far. Im not sure how to select certain characters in a field.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim streamer As IO.StreamReader

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    Dim ofd1 As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofd1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = ofd1.FileName
    End If
    streamer = IO.File.OpenText(ofd1.FileName)
    Label3.Text = IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd1.FileName).Length
    Dim MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ofd1.FileName)
    MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(currentRow(0))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(currentRow(1))
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End While



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a combination of string.Substring and string.Length

```
ListBox2.Items.Add(currentRow(1).Substring(currentRow(1).Length - 4))
```

The same in an expanded form and with some checks on the length value

```
Dim startPos = currentRow(1).Length - 4
If startPos < 0 Then
    startPos = 0
End If
Dim last4CharString = currentRow(1).Substring(startPos)
ListBox2.Items.Add(last4CharString)
```

By the way, I think you could remove these lines
(You read the whole file just to discover the lines present, then you read it again with the TextFieldParser)

```
streamer = IO.File.OpenText(ofd1.FileName)
Label3.Text = IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd1.FileName).Length
```

Instead use a `lineCounter` inside the TextFieldParser loop and increment it at each loop.
Then set the final value to the Label text.

```
Dim lineCounter = 0
While Not MyReader.EndOfData
    ....
    lineCounter +=1
End While
Label3.Text = lineCounter.ToString
```